# Time profiler related error in Xcode profiler: Instruments

Tags: ios, swift, metal, instruments

While profiling an app (which has metal codes for gpu acceleration) Time Profiler Instrument gives the error as in the screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

It says, No configuration information received.

I want to know what kind of configuration is missing and how to configure it. I have also observed that other instruments: Allocations, Leaks, VM Tracker has no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure OSX, XCode and the device's iOS are all fully up to date and power cycle everything. If that doesn't fix it, I'd temporarily modify the app's deployment target to the highest possible option.

If that doesn't fix it check to see if it happens using the metal demo (XCode->File->New->Project->iOS Game Metal) then look to file a bug with Apple: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/

Comment: I am using a cloud machine (rented machine) with Big Sur version 11.4, Xcode 12.5.1 and I am using iPhone7 Simulator.

Modifying deployment target didn't helped.

Comment: What version iOS in the sim? Have you tried on actual hardware?

Comment: I don't think profiling with simulator will give you any useful info whatsoever

Comment: @JeshuaLacock ios 14.3 in simulator

Comment: @JustSomeGuy will try in actual device and update about it